# split a multi-page pdf file into multiple pdf files with python?

Tags: python, pdf

I would like to take a multi-page pdf file and create separate pdf files per page.

I have downloaded [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.org/index.html) and have browsed the documentation, but it seems aimed at pdf generation. I haven't yet seen anything about processing PDF files themselves.

Is there an easy way to do this in python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated solution for the latest release of PyPDF (3.0.0) and to split a range of pages.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

file_name = r'c:\temp\junk.pdf'
pages = (121, 130)

reader = PdfReader(file_name)
writer = PdfWriter()
page_range = range(pages[0], pages[1] + 1)

for page_num, page in enumerate(reader.pages, 1):
    if page_num in page_range:
        writer.add_page(page)

with open(f'{file_name}_page_{pages[0]}-{pages[1]}.pdf', 'wb') as out:
    writer.write(out)
```

Answer (score 239):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

inputpdf = PdfReader(open("document.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(len(inputpdf.pages)):
    output = PdfWriter()
    output.add_page(inputpdf.pages[i])
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

etc.

Comment: User `with open("document-page%s.pdf" % (i+1), "wb") as outputStream:` if you want your files to be named with index starting from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: if you are having `PdfReadError: Multiple definitions in dictionary at byte`, you can modify your input pdf variable to: `pdf = PdfFileReader(open("document.pdf", "rb"), strict=False)`

Comment: If i want to split 100 instead of split 1 page individual i want to save 2 in 1 pdf. I change the for to save two pages at a time, right?

Comment: The issue I ran into with this code was as I was "extracting" each page and iterating through the document, the next output would contain all previous pages. For example, a document _"test.pdf"_ containing 5 pages and to be renamed _"test_(page num).pdf"_ would give me a result where the first iteration was fine (one page) but the next iteration would contain pages1-2, then the next would be pages 1-3...and so on.

My fix for this was to simply add another `PdfFileReader` **_inside_** the for loop

Comment: I was in a hurry, the script did great! but before that, I had some problems with the PyPDF version, to make it run I had to downgrade with: pip install PyPDF2==2.12.1              (didn't had time to adjust to a proper fix)

Answer (score 11):

I missed here a solution where you split the PDF to two parts consisting of all pages so I append my solution if somebody was looking for the same:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def split_pdf_to_two(filename,page_number):
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))
    try:
        assert page_number < pdf_reader.numPages
        pdf_writer1 = PdfFileWriter()
        pdf_writer2 = PdfFileWriter()

        for page in range(page_number):
            pdf_writer1.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

        for page in range(page_number,pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
            pdf_writer2.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

        with open("part1.pdf", 'wb') as file1:
            pdf_writer1.write(file1)

        with open("part2.pdf", 'wb') as file2:
            pdf_writer2.write(file2)

    except AssertionError as e:
        print("Error: The PDF you are cutting has less pages than you want to cut!")
```

Answer (score 9):

The PyPDF2 package gives you the ability to split up a single PDF into multiple ones.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

    output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(fname, page+1)

    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

    print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
```

Changes for PyPDF2 3.0.0

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
path = 'pdf_forms/myform.pdf'
fname = 'fname'

pdf = PdfReader(path)
for page in range(len(pdf.pages)):
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    pdf_writer.add_page(pdf.pages[page])

    output_filename =         
     'pdf_forms/splitted/{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(fname, page+1)

    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

    print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))
```

Source: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/04/11/splitting-and-merging-pdfs-with-python/

Comment: added page number selection and wrapped it in a function: https://gist.github.com/shanecandoit/b3b90fa4532aeedce6400c0084981933

Comment: I want to split a 169 pages pdf to 85 containing 2 pages in each file. It's possible do say that i want 2 pages instead 1?

Answer (score 4):

```py
import fitz

src = fitz.open("source.pdf")
for page in src:
    tar = fitz.open()  # output PDF for 1 page
    # copy over current page
    tar.insert_pdf(src, from_page=page.number, to_page=page.number)
    tar.save(f"page-{page.number}.pdf")
    tar.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

The earlier answers with `PyPDF2` for splitting pdfs are not working anymore with the latest version update. The authors recommend using `pypdf` instead and this version of `PyPDF2==3.0.1` will be the last version of `PyPDF2`. The function needs to be modified as follows:

```py
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def split_pdfs(input_file_path):
    inputpdf = PdfReader(open(input_file_path, "rb"))

    out_paths = []
    if not os.path.exists("outputs"):
        os.makedirs("outputs")

    for i, page in enumerate(inputpdf.pages):
        output = PdfWriter()
        output.add_page(page)

        out_file_path = f"outputs/{input_file_path[:-4]}_{i}.pdf"
        with open(out_file_path, "wb") as output_stream:
            output.write(output_stream)

        out_paths.append(out_file_path)
    return out_paths
```

Note: The same function will work with `pypdf` as well. Import `PdfReader` and `PdfWriter` from `pypdf` rather than `PyPDF2`.

Answer (score 3):

I know that the code is not related to python, however i felt like posting this piece of R code which is simple, flexible and works amazingly. The PDFtools package in R is amazing in splitting merging PDFs at ease.

```
library(pdftools) #Rpackage
pdf_subset('D:\\file\\20.02.20\\22 GT 2017.pdf',
           pages = 1:51, output = "subset.pdf")
```

Comment: Here number of pages is hardcoded. Anyway to automatically do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
import sys
import glob
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    _location_ = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.executable))
elif __file__:
    _location_ = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

for file in glob.glob(__location__ + "/*.pdf"):
    if file.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdf_file = open(os.path.join(__location__, file), 'rb')
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        
pageNumbers = pdf_reader.getNumPages()

for i in range (pageNumbers):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(i))
    split_motive = open('Page ' + str(i+1) + '.pdf', 'wb')
    pdf_writer.write(split_motive)
    split_motive.close()

pdf_file.close()
```

[Link to article](https://rafalkobus.wordpress.com/2023/03/06/split-pdf-file-to-single-page-pdf-files/)

Answer (score -1):

```py
import fitz  # Importing the fitz library

# specify the path of the PDF file
pdf_path = "2021.pdf"

# open the PDF
try:
    pdf = fitz.open(pdf_path)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
```

- **Importing fitz**: The `fitz` library is used for working with PDF files and images.
- **Open PDF**: The script attempts to open a PDF file located at `"2021.pdf"`. If the file doesn't exist at the specified path, it catches a `FileNotFoundError` and prints "File not found".

```py
# iterate over the pages starting from the 6th page
for i, page in enumerate(pdf[6:], start=6):
    try:
        # render the page as a JPEG image
        pix = page.get_pixmap(alpha=False)
        # save the image
        pix.writeJPG(f"page_{i+1}.jpg")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

- **Iterating Over Pages**: The script iterates over the pages of the PDF starting from the 6th page. Python uses zero-based indexing, so `pdf[6:]` refers to the 7th page onwards.
- **Rendering Pages as Images**: For each page, it converts the page into a `pixmap`, which is an image representation of the page. The `alpha=False` parameter is used to specify that the image should not include transparency.
- **Saving Images**: Each page image is saved as a JPEG file. The filenames are generated to reflect the page numbers (`page_{i+1}.jpg`). The enumeration starts at 6, but we increment it by 1 to reflect the actual page numbers starting from 7.

```py
# close the PDF
print("Successful")
pdf.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**