# How to "write to variable" instead of "to file" in Python

Tags: python, pdf, io, outputstream, pypdf

I'm trying to write a function which splits a pdf into separate pages. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/490203/1650012). I copied a simple function which splits a pdf into separate pages:

```
def splitPdf(file_):
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file_)
    pages = []
    for i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
        with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
            output.write(outputStream)
    return pages
```

This however, writes the new PDFs to file, instead of returning a list of the new PDFs as file variables. So I changed the line of `output.write(outputStream)` to:

```
pages.append(outputStream)
```

When trying to write the elements in the pages list however, I get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.

Does anybody know how I can add the new files to the list and return them, instead of writing them to file? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Have you tried reading the data, rather than storing the file handle - `pages.append(outputStream.read())`?

Comment: Have you tried using `cStringIO.StringIO` to open `outputStream`?

Comment: what the user above said... you can usually substitute a `StringIO` object for a file and get the result out as a string that way

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I just tried it, and that gives me a `IOError: File not open for reading` on the line saying `pages.append(outputStream.read())`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user4815162342 - Ehm, no I haven't tried StringIO. Any tips on how to do that? A code example would be very welcome.. :)

Comment: What is the use case. You want to have a list of file handles to operate on after you called splitPdf? Can`t you just have a list of path instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you mean by "list of PDFs as file *variables*. If you want to create strings instead of files with PDF contents, and return a list of such strings, replace `open()` with `StringIO` and call `getvalue()` to obtain the contents:

```
import cStringIO

def splitPdf(file_):
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file_)
    pages = []
    for i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
        io = cStringIO.StringIO()
        output.write(io)
        pages.append(io.getvalue())
    return pages
```

Comment: (This answer is Python 2 only)

Comment: @Garrett It should be quite straightforward to adapt to Python 3, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the in-memory binary streams in the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html) module. This will store the pdf files in your memory.

```
import io

def splitPdf(file_):
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file_)
    pages = []
    for i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        outputStream = io.BytesIO()

        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
        output.write(outputStream)

        # Move the stream position to the beginning,
        # making it easier for other code to read
        outputStream.seek(0)

        pages.append(outputStream)
    return pages
```

To later write the objects to a file, use `shutil.copyfileobj`:

```
import shutil

with open('page0.pdf', 'wb') as out:
    shutil.copyfileobj(pages[0], out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used PdfFileWriter, but think that this should work.

```
def splitPdf(file_):
    pdf = PdfFileReader(file_)
    pages = []
    for i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
        pages.append(output)
    return pages

def writePdf(pages):
    i = 1
    for p in pages:
        with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
            p.write(outputStream)
        i += 1
```