# PyPDF2 PdfFileWriter has no attribute stream

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to split a pdf into its pages and save each page as a new pdf. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490195/split-a-multi-page-pdf-file-into-multiple-pdf-files-with-python) method from a previous question with no success and the pypdf2 split example from [here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167) with no success. EDIT: I can see in my files that it does successfully write the first page, the second page pdf is then created but is empty.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("my_pdf.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_functions.py", line 9, in <module>
    output.write(outputStream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 482, in write
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 572, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 548, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 572, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 548, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 557, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 572, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 548, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 575, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    if data.pdf.stream.closed:
AttributeError: 'PdfFileWriter' object has no attribute 'stream'
```

I also tried this and confirmed that I can indeed extract a single page.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("/home/ubuntu/inputs/cityshape/form5.pdf", "rb"))

#for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(2))
with open("document-page2.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: working fine on ubuntu too [img](https://postimg.org/image/rujz7kqyx/)

Comment: Did a clean install and works fine now, weird that it all worked fine outside of the for loop. Thanks for your help @Hisham.

Comment: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 13):

The same thing happened to me.

I was able to solve it by moving the following line inside the loop:

`inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("/home/ubuntu/inputs/cityshape/form5.pdf", "rb"))`

I believe that some versions of PyPDF2 have some sort of bug, that when you invoke the`PdfFileWriter.write` method, it messes with the PdfFileReader instance. By recreating the PdfFileReader instance after each write, it bypasses this bug.

The following code should work (untested):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

pdf_in_file = open("my_pdf.pdf",'rb')

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_in_file)
pages_no = inputpdf.numPages

for i in range(pages_no):
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_in_file)
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)

pdf_in_file.close()
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks. Maybe the `PdfFileWriter.write` method consumes the stream? Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error "AttributeError: 'PdfFileWriter' object has no attribute 'stream'" by repeating opening the PDF.

My old code:

```
pdf = PdfFileReader('arq.pfd')
pagi = 14
pagf = 20
dic = PdfFileMerger()

for i in range(pagi -1, pagf):

  pag = PdfFileWriter()
  pag.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))

  with open('pag.pdf', 'wb') as split:

    pag.write(split)

  pag = PdfFileReader('pag.pdf')
  dic.append(pag)

with open(f'PDF ({pagi} - {pagf}).pdf', 'wb') as split:

  dic.write(split)

!rm pag.pdf
```

My new code:

```
pdf = PdfFileReader('arq.pdf')
pagi = 14
pagf = 20
dic = PdfFileMerger()

for i in range(pagi - 1, pagf):

  pag = PdfFileWriter()
  pag.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))

  with open('pag.pdf', 'wb') as split:

    pdf = PdfFileReader('arq.pdf') # Adding pdf again
    pag.write(split)

  pag = PdfFileReader('pag.pdf')
  dic.append(pag)

with open(f'PDF ({pagi} - {pagf}).pdf', 'wb') as split:

  dic.write(split)

!rm pag.pdf
```

Hugs!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem today. But I found so many code just like me without errors, so I think maybe just version error. I have used pypdf2 version==1.27.3, just change it version to 1.25.0, this error will fix.

```
pip install pypdf2==1.25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in version [1.27.8](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/releases/tag/1.27.8)