# Python code to extract a 20x20 clip at x, and y location on nth page of all pdf docs in given directory

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pypdf

I m trying to write a Python code to extract a 20x20 image clip at x, and y location on nth page of all pdf documents in given directory. All clips then to be joined (say horizontally) together and saved as jpg file in the directory of pdf files.

I have written following python code using pypdf and images library but it gives below errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Tehseen\Progs\.venv\pdfextract.py", line 62, in <module>
    main(directory_path, x_position, y_position)
  File "c:\Tehseen\Progs\.venv\pdfextract.py", line 41, in main
    image = extract_image_from_pdf(pdf_path, x, y, 1)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Tehseen\Progs\.venv\pdfextract.py", line 21, in extract_image_from_pdf
    img_data = x_object.stream.get_data()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'EncodedStreamObject' object has no attribute 'stream'
```

```
import os
import PyPDF2
from PIL import Image
import io

def extract_image_from_pdf(pdf_path, x, y, n):
    """
    Extract a 20x20 image clip from the nth page of a PDF at the specified (x, y) location.
    """
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        if n < 1 or n > len(pdf_reader.pages):
            raise ValueError(f"Page number {n} is out of range for PDF {pdf_path}")
        
        page = pdf_reader.pages[n - 1]
        x_objects = page.get('/Resources', {}).get('/XObject', {})
        
        for obj_key in x_objects:
            if x_objects[obj_key].get('/Subtype') == '/Image':
                x_object = x_objects[obj_key]
                img_data = x_object.stream.get_data()
                img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
                
                # Crop the 20x20 clip from the specified (x, y) location
                box = (x, y, x + 20, y + 20)
                cropped_image = img.crop(box)
                
                return cropped_image
    return None

def main(directory, x, y):
    """
    Extract and join 20x20 image clips from all PDFs in the specified directory.
    """
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdf_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            
            # Extract image from the 1st page of each PDF
            image = extract_image_from_pdf(pdf_path, x, y, 1)
            if image:
                images.append(image)
    
    # Combine all images horizontally
    total_width = 20 * len(images)
    max_height = 20
    combined_image = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

    x_offset = 0
    for image in images:
        combined_image.paste(image, (x_offset, 0))
        x_offset += 20

    # Save the combined image as a JPG file
    combined_image.save('combined_image.jpg')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory_path = 'C:/Tehseen/temp/Screens'
    x_position = 10  # Replace with the desired x-coordinate
    y_position = 10  # Replace with the desired y-coordinate
    main(directory_path, x_position, y_position)`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168027/pypdf2-pdffilewriter-has-no-attribute-stream