# Split specific pages of PDF and save it with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to split 20 pages of pdf file (single) , into five respective pdf files ,  1st pdf contains 1-3 pages , 2nd pdf file contains only 4th page, 3rd pdf contains 5 to 10 pages, 4th pdf contains 11-17 pages , and 5th pdf contains 18-20 page . I need the working code in python. The below mentioned code splits the entire pdf file into single pages, but I want the grouped pages..

```
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("input.pdf", "rb"))
    for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    j = i+1    
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("page%s.pdf" % j, "wb") as outputStream:
    output.write(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it looks like task for [pdfrw](https://pypi.org/project/pdfrw/) using this [example from GitHub](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/blob/master/examples/subset.py) I written following example code:

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter
pages = PdfReader('inputfile.pdf').pages
parts = [(3,6),(7,10)]
for part in parts:
    outdata = PdfWriter(f'pages_{part[0]}_{part[1]}.pdf')
    for pagenum in range(*part):
        outdata.addpage(pages[pagenum-1])
    outdata.write()
```

This one create two files: `pages_3_6.pdf` and `pages_7_10.pdf` each with 3 pages i.e. 3,4,5 and 7,8,9. Note `pagenum-1` in code, that `-1` is used due to fact that pdf pages numeration starts at `1` rather than `0`. I also used so-called f-strings to get names of output files. In my opinion it is slick method but it is not available in Python2 and I am not sure if it is available in all Python3 versions (I tested my code in `3.6.7`), so you might use old formatting method instead if you wish.
Remember to alter filenames and ranges accordingly to your needs.

Comment: parts = [(1,3),(4),(5,10),(11,17),(18,20)]
for part in parts:
    outdata = PdfWriter(f'pages_{part[0]}_{part[1]}.pdf')
    for pagenum in range(*part):
            outdata.addpage(pages[pagenum-1])
    outdata.write()  the  split code is not working for the above case kindly help.

Comment: @SutirthaThakur: `parts` have to be `list` of 2-`tuple`s so `(4)` is not legal. You should use `(4,5)` instead. Also keep in mind `(1,3)` means pages 1,2 and `(4,5)` means page 4.

Comment: parts = [(1,4),(4,5),(5,10),(10,20)] when I am entering this I am getting IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @SutirthaThakur: please check if your .pdf file actually have so many pages, I do not see any other possible reason for `IndexError`.

Comment: It contains 20 pages only

Comment: Please add line `print(len(pages))` below `pages = PdfReader...` this will show how many pages were actually readed.

Comment: its saying 12 but the it should be 20 , ideally speaking

Comment: Then this mean `PdfReader` for some reason did not load whole .pdf, it is beyond my capability to solve this issue

Comment: input_file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('input.pdf') this works fine

Answer (score 1):

**How to extract specific pages (or split specific pages) from a PDF file and save those pages as a separate PDF using Python.**

```
pip install PyPDF2 # to install module/package

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_file_path = 'Unknown.pdf'
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')

pdf = PdfReader(pdf_file_path)

pages = [0, 2, 4] # page 1, 3, 5
pdfWriter = PdfWriter()

for page_num in pages:
    pdfWriter.add_page(pdf.pages[page_num])

with open('{0}_subset.pdf'.format(file_base_name), 'wb') as f:
    pdfWriter.write(f)
    f.close()
```

**CREDIT :**
[How to extract PDF pages and save as a separate PDF file using Python](https://learndataanalysis.org/how-to-extract-pdf-pages-and-save-as-a-separate-pdf-file-using-python/)

Answer (score -1):

if you have python 3, you can use tika according to the following answer here:

[How to extract text from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file)

Comment: I want to split pages , then I want the extraction

Comment: @SutirthaThakur [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490195/split-a-multi-page-pdf-file-into-multiple-pdf-files-with-python) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to split it page wise ,  only  selected pages are required , if possible share the code.