# How to solve MemoryError using Python 3.7 pdf2image library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory, data-conversion

I'm running a simple PDF to image conversion using Python PDF2Image library. I can certainly understand that the max memory threshold is being crossed by this library to arrive at this error. But, [the PDF](https://www.pwc.nl/nl/assets/documents/pwc-annual-report-2017-2018.pdf) is 6.6 MB (approx), then why would it take up GBs of memory to throw a memory error?

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pdf2image import convert_from_path
>>> pages = convert_from_path(r'C:\Users\aakashba598\Documents\pwc-annual-report-2017-2018.pdf', 200)
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aakashba598\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\aakashba598\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aakashba598\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1215, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
MemoryError
```

Also, what is the possible solution to this?

Update: When I reduced the dpi parameter from the **convert_from_path** function, it works like a charm. But the pictures produced are low quality (for obvious reasons). Is there a way to fix this? Like batch by batch creation of images and clearing memory everytime. If there is a way, how to go about it?

Comment: Do you have to use Python, or can you also use imagemagick?

Comment: I want to do it through coding and Python is a very handy programming language.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Convert the PDF in chunks of 10 pages at a time (1-10, 11-20... and so on)

```py
from pdf2image import pdfinfo_from_path, convert_from_path
info = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_file, userpw=None, poppler_path=None)

maxPages = info["Pages"]
for page in range(1, maxPages+1, 10) : 
    convert_from_path(pdf_file, dpi=200, first_page=page, last_page = min(page+10-1,maxPages))
```

Comment: Very short, crisp and a brilliant solution. Thank you!

Comment: I got, 'pdf2image' has no attribute '_page_count'. Any idea what this is about?

Comment: pdf2image._page_count is undocumented function of the module. maybe it was removed or renamed.

Comment: Try from pdf2image.pdf2image import pdfinfo_from_path then pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_file, userpw=None, poppler_path=None)["Pages"]

Answer (score 13):

I am a bit late to this, but the problem is indeed related to the 136 pages going into memory. You can do three things.

1. Specify a format for the converted images.

By default, pdf2image uses PPM as its image format, it is faster, but also takes a lot more memory (over 30MB per image!). What you can do to fix this is use a more memory-friendly format like jpeg or png.

```
convert_from_path('C:\path\to\your\pdf', fmt='jpeg')
```

That will probably solve the problem, but it's mostly just because of the compression, and at some point (say for +500pages PDF) the problem will reappear.

2. Use an output directory

This is the one I would recommend because it allows you to process any PDF. The example on the README page explains it well:

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
    images_from_path = convert_from_path('C:\path\to\your\pdf', output_folder=path)
```

This writes the image to your computer storage temporarily so you don't have to delete it manually. Make sure to do any processing you need to do before exiting the `with` context though!

3. Process the PDF file in chunks

`pdf2image` allows you to define the first an last page that you want to process. That means that in your case, with a PDF of 136 pages, you could do:

```
for i in range(0, 136 // 10 + 1):
    convert_from_path('C:\path\to\your\pdf', first_page=i*10, last_page=(i+1)*10)
```

Comment: Concerning processing the PDF in chunks: in latest version of `convert_from_path` there's no `first` and `last`, instead it's `first_page` and `last_page`

Comment: @EugeneChabanov it's always been first_page and last_page, I just missed it when I first wrote the answer. I'll update it.

Comment: Does option #2 just write the images to storage instead of keeping them in memory?  And if so, is the only advantage of using `tempfile` that it is garbage collected, or is there better performance for some reason?

Comment: Also, it seems from the [documentation](https://pdf2image.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#functions) that in `convert_from_path` the `first_page` and `last_page` are both inclusive, which I also confirmed through use, so it should be `last_page = (i+1)*10 - 1`.

Comment: Actually, from using `convert_from_path`, it seems that the pages are not zero indexed, so that the first page of the PDF is page 1, so it should be `first_page=i*10 + 1` and `last_page=(i+1)*10`.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer has a small issue.

> `maxPages = pdf2image._page_count(pdf_file)`

can no longer be used, as `_page_count` is deprecated. I found the working solution for the same.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader    
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(pdf, "rb"))
maxPages = inputpdf.numPages
for page in range(1, maxPages, 100):
    pil_images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf, dpi=200, first_page=page,
                                                     last_page=min(page + 100 - 1, maxPages), fmt= 'jpg',
                                                     thread_count=1, userpw=None,
                                                     use_cropbox=False, strict=False)
```

This way, however large the file, it will process 100 at once and the ram usage is always minimal.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively big PDF will use up all your memory and cause the process to be killed (unless you use an output folder)
https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image i guess will help you to understand.

Solution: Break the pdf in small parts and convert it into image. The image could be merge...

```
 from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

 inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("document.pdf", "rb"))

 for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
     output = PdfFileWriter()
     output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
     with open("document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
         output.write(outputStream)
```

[split a multi-page pdf file into multiple pdf files with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490195/split-a-multi-page-pdf-file-into-multiple-pdf-files-with-python)

```
 import numpy as np
 import PIL

 list_im = ['Test1.jpg', 'Test2.jpg', 'Test3.jpg']
 imgs    = [ PIL.Image.open(i) for i in list_im ]
 # pick the image which is the smallest, and resize the others to match it (can be   arbitrary image shape here)
 min_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
 imgs_comb = np.hstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_shape) ) for i in imgs ) )

 # save that beautiful picture
 imgs_comb = PIL.Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
 imgs_comb.save( 'Trifecta.jpg' )    

 # for a vertical stacking it is simple: use vstack
 imgs_comb = np.vstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_shape) ) for i in imgs ) )
 imgs_comb = PIL.Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
 imgs_comb.save( 'Trifecta_vertical.jpg' )
```

refer:[Combine several images horizontally with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227466/combine-several-images-horizontally-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

eventually, combining these techniques, I ended up coding like following, given the goal to convert a pdf into a pptx with avoiding memory overflow and good speed in mind:

```
import os, sys, tempfile, pprint
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import pdfinfo_from_path,convert_from_path
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from io import BytesIO

pdf_file = sys.argv[1]
print("Converting file: " + pdf_file)

# Prep presentation
prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]

# Create working folder
base_name = pdf_file.split(".pdf")[0]

# Convert PDF to list of images
print("Starting conversion...")
print()
path: str = "C:/ppttemp"  #temp dir (use cron to delete files older than 1h hourly)
slideimgs = []
info = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_file, userpw=None, poppler_path='C:/Program Files/poppler-0.90.1/bin/')
maxPages = info["Pages"]
for page in range(1, maxPages+1, 5) : 
   slideimgs.extend( convert_from_path(pdf_file, dpi=250, output_folder=path, first_page=page, last_page = min(page+5-1,maxPages), fmt='jpeg', thread_count=4, poppler_path='C:/Program Files/poppler-0.90.1/bin/', use_pdftocairo=True)   )

print("...complete.")
print()

# Loop over slides
for i, slideimg in enumerate(slideimgs):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        print("Saving slide: " + str(i))

    imagefile = BytesIO()
    slideimg.save(imagefile, format='jpeg')
    imagedata = imagefile.getvalue()
    imagefile.seek(0)
    width, height = slideimg.size

    # Set slide dimensions
    prs.slide_height = height * 9525
    prs.slide_width = width * 9525

    # Add slide
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(imagefile, 0, 0, width=width * 9525, height=height * 9525)
    

# Save Powerpoint
print("Saving file: " + base_name + ".pptx")
prs.save(base_name + '.pptx')
print("Conversion complete. :)")
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code converts a PDF in chunks and then adds the images to an array:

```py
from pdf2image import pdfinfo_from_path, convert_from_path

PDF = "/path/to/pdf.pdf"
CHUNK_SIZE = 20 # depends on your RAM
MAX_PAGES = pdfinfo_from_path(PDF)["Pages"]

images = []
for page in range(1, MAX_PAGES, CHUNK_SIZE):
    images += convert_from_path(PDF, first_page=page, last_page=page + CHUNK_SIZE - 1)
```