# How to convert every page of pdf to a pdf object using python

Tags: pdf-generation, pypdf, pdfminer, pdfplumber

I want to create each page of a pdf file to a new pdf object. I am following the mentioned code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/490203/13291630 but here it is shown as the creation of a new file, but I want to just create a pdf object without creating a new file and just use that created pdf object as every other pdf. I hope this information helps, Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your purpose:

```
import pdfplumber
filename = 'path/to/your/PDF'
pages = []
with pdfplumber.open(filename) as pdf:
    for i, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        pages.append(page)
```

The list `pages` will contain an element of class `page` for every actual page of you PDF. You can then access their properties. Look at [PDFPlumber Github page](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) for more information